# $\sum a_n$ absolutely converges iff $\sum (\frac {n+1}{n})^{n-1}a_n$ absolutely converges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ absolutely converges iff $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac {n+1}{n})^{n-1}a_n$ absolutely converges.

I think this is right.

Can I do this:

$|(\frac {n+1}{n})^{n-1}a_n| \leq$ (since $1+1/n>1$) $|(1+1/n)^na_n|\leq$ (since $(1+1/n)^n$ is increasing and bounded and $e$ is its limit so it is the sup of $(1+1/n)^n$) $|ea_n|$.

$\sum |a_n|$ converges so $\sum |ea_n|$ also  converges, therefore $\sum |(\frac {n+1}{n})^{n-1}a_n|$ converges as well.
This proves $\Longrightarrow$.

Now, wlog assuming that $a_n\neq 0$  look at $\frac {|(\frac {n+1}{n})^{n-1}a_n|}{|a_n|}=|(\frac {n+1}{n})^{n-1}|\to e>0$ so assuming that  $\sum |(\frac {n+1}{n})^{n-1}a_n|$ we get that $\sum |a_n|$ also converges.

I guess that this can be shown in a shorther way.. what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is bascially correct. Here is a shorter way, not using the limit comparision test, but the usual comparision test. We also don't need to know the increasing of $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$.

Note that
$$1\leq\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n-1}\leq \left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n}\leq 3,\qquad n\geq 1.\tag{1}$$
A simple proof of last inequality: Since $2^{k-1}=2\cdot2\cdot\cdots 2<2\cdot3\cdot\cdots k=k!$ for $k\geq 2$,
we have
$$\left(1+{1\over n}\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}\left({1\over n}\right)^k\leq \sum_{k=0}^\infty{1\over k!}\leq 1+1+\sum_{k=2}^\infty {1\over 2^{k-1}} =3.$$

**Added:** $(1)$ implies that
$$|a_n|\leq \left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n-1}|a_n|\leq 3|a_n|.$$
If $\sum |a_n|<\infty$, then $\sum 3|a_n|<\infty$ and thus $\sum \left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n-1}|a_n|<\infty$. On the other hand, if $\sum \left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n-1}|a_n|<\infty$, then using $|a_n|\leq \left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n-1}|a_n|$, we have $\sum |a_n|<\infty$.

Comment: Thanks.  What is important in the left inequality is that it is >0 right, and cannot we just say that the right inequality <3 since $(1+1/n)^n\leq e<3$ ? @Feng

Comment: @Bestmat The proof of $(1+1/n)^n\leq e$ is much more non-trivial than the proof of $(1+1/n)^n<3$. That's why I said "shorter".

Comment: However does the inequality you wroe proves the iff?

Comment: @Bestmat I've added it in my answer.